# Can you select data from specify Table/Database with condition?

Tags: sql, ado

I'm using ADO to query thing from database (excel file, accdb, mdb...)
what is confusing me now: Is it possible to select table/DB with condition setting up inside SQL ?
normally:

```
 SELECT Field1 FROM table1
```

what I expect:

```
if A=2 then SELECT F1 FROM table1 else SELECT F1 from table2
```

Or like this:

```
SELECT F1 from switch(A=2, table1, true, Table2)
```

I can do this in VB by creating SQL string from condition, but I don't know if any native SQL statement can do this ? (switch table/ExternalDB to select)

Comment: Yes you can do that but that is basically along the line of the same to the vb. You can create dynamic sql.

Comment: It's better done in vb/c# than in SQL. Generate SQL based on the variable and then execute

Comment: Thank guy, code the SQL string is too ez. I just want to see if there is a way using native SQL (but not reduce performance in overall).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in dynamic SQL most easily.  That is, construct the query that you want.

Otherwise, you can do:

```
SELECT F1
FROM table1
WHERE "A" = 2
UNION ALL
SELECT F1
FROM table2
WHERE "A" <> 2;
```

That is, `UNION ALL` combines the two possibilities.  The `"A"` represents the fact that `A` is a variable.  The exact syntax depends on the database and access mechanism.

Comment: this way I think overall performance will drop alot if table1 and table2 content a lot of data (over 1m rows). after all, you did show me it's possible... Thank Gordon.
just, if there are more than 2 table, dynamic number of table, it'll be complex more than the problem itself lol

Comment: @Sum . . . Whether a query reads any data from tables when a constant condition is false depends on the database optimizer.  Most optimizers will return an empty result set very quickly.

Comment: the problem is like this, there are 3 tables same format, each table content specify month (tbl1 1->4, tbl2 5->9, tbl3 10->12). if I only need to query data from a whatever month ( 1 to 12) then I has to query from a UNION ALL (tbl1+tbl2+tbl3) <--- this slowdown process. So I try to find the trick that make PC smart enough to load only necessary table (since each table content over 1m records).

Answer (score 0):

if you're using VB then:

```
sql = "select f1 from " & if(A=2,"table1", "table2")
```

You can do this in basically any language.